# Sending a "message" from server-side to client-side

Tags: javascript, client-server, ipc, rpc, json-rpc

We developed a web application (HTML/CSS/JavaScript on client-side, web services on server-side). Each user action on client-side calls to some web method on server-side.

But we have some problems when user opens more than one browser tab with our application, so we decided to force logout in all browser's tabs (excluding the current tab) each time when user login in different browser's tab.
How we could implement that client-side will be able to receive "messages" from the server-side?

Comment: Should be closed! Just use websockets like autobahn.ws / node.js / ....

Comment: I think, you should add some unique id's / tokens for each user / client application instance so each tab would create one and there would be no conflicts, instead of closing all tabs (but Telegram still does that)

Comment: I'd suggest instead of doing this, you change the application to be friendly to the user's preferred way of working (multiple tabs), rather than surprising and probably irritating the user by logging them out in other tabs when then open a new one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem is that when more than one tab is open and user change things in one of the tabs you have to sync the data dysplayed in ALL the tabs. It's a little complicated to implement. Therefore we dicided to force logout in non-current tabs. Are you agree with what Tobias proposed?

Comment: @TobiasK. Interesting. Could you please suggest some tutorial or simple examples we could use?

Comment: @Ilan Have a look at http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/

Answer (score 3):

When you say sending a message from server-side to client-side I assume that you don't want a response on Node.js like:

`res.status(200).send('Hello World')` don't you?

So, what you need is using websockets. I recommend you to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

You only need to send a message with a socket on your server side and listen for that message on your client side.

Using websockets you can send a message to each user identified with an Id, or sending message in a broadcast. There are a lot of possibilities with websockests.

You can find examples on the web using websockets. I think that is what you are looking for.